# kivy scroll view just shows black screen

Tags: python, kivy

I'm currently learning kivy and was following a tutorial, while following the tutorial I ran into a problem where uppon running my code only a black screen appears

this is what my .py file looks like:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.app import App


class stack_layout_example(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        """
        # orientation without the kv
        self.orientation = "lr-bt"
        """
        for i in range(0, 100):
            size = 100
            button = Button(
                text = str(i+1),
                size_hint=(None, None),
                #    ( width , height )
                size=(size, size)
            )
            self.add_widget(button)

class the_labApp(App):
    pass

the_labApp().run()
```

and this is my .kv file:

```
scroll_view_example:

<scroll_view_example@ScrollView>:
    stack_layout_example:

<stack_layout_example>:
```

Comment: Class names in kivy should start with capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `build` method in the `the_labApp` app. It should be like the following code snippet:

```py
class the_labApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return stack_layout_example()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Thank You very much for your answers guys... I already found the solution in the kivy discord

i just re-arrange the .kv file to

```
<ScrollViewExample@ScrollView>:
    StackLayoutExample:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height

<StackLayoutExample>:

ScrollViewExample:
```

also the kv looks a bit different now because it now follows pep8(i think)